# Java - Using JOptionPane to display dialog that is read from a text file

Tags: java

I am working on a project for a zookeeper to monitor animals.  The zookeeper chooses to monitor an animal who's data is stored in a text file.

If there is important data that needs to be displayed in a dialog box, it contains "*****".  If an animal with important info is entered, I am only able to get 2 dialog boxes to display the important info of the other two animals. I want it to show a dialog box with the important information of only the animal that was entered.  I hope that makes sense, here is my code:

```
animalsbr = getBufferedReader("animals.txt");
    try {   
        while ((currentLine = animalsbr.readLine()) != null) {
            if (currentLine.contains("Animal - " + userAnimal)) {
                // loop until an empty line is found
                do {
                    System.out.println(currentLine = animalsbr.readLine());
                } while (!currentLine.contains("Feeding"));
                System.out.println();                    
            }
            if (currentLine.contains("*****")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ATENTION, " + userName + ": " + currentLine.substring(5));
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        System.out.println(fnfe);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println(ioe);
```

The formatting is kind of weird, but my text file reads:

Details on lions

Details on bears

Details on dogs

Animal - Lion

Name: Leo

Age: 5

*****Health concerns: Cut on left front paw

Feeding schedule: Twice daily

Animal - Bear

Name: Baloo

Age: 1

Health concerns: None

*****Feeding schedule: None on record

Animal - Dog

Name: Zelda

Age: 1

*****Health concerns: Scratch on left cheek

Feeding schedule: Once a day at 7pm

---

So with the code I have, if the user enters "Lion", dialog boxes pop up that display the lines with asterisks from the bear and dog's information, but not the lion's.  I tried using mark and reset but couldn't figure anything out with that. How should I fix this?

Comment: First, format your code correctly, so that the closing brackets line up with the opening control structure. Next go through your code with a debugger. Step by step.

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips on how to debug your program.

Comment: “I want it to show a dialog box with the important information of only the animal that was entered.”  Think about that for a moment.  If you find a matching `Animal - …` line, you want to display a dialog for only that animal.  Perhaps your code which displays that dialog should be inside the body of the `if` statement which checks for the requested animal?